# Passing JavaScript variables to PHP function using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

In my **dashboard.php** I have a Javascript function that is called based on the user clicking a button. When the button is clicked, it calls a JavaScript function called `getTeamMembers` and values are passed across to it. The values passed across to this function are then sent to a PHP function (which is also located in dashboard.php).

However I am not getting any success and was hoping that someone could guide me on where I am going wrong. I am a noob when it comes to AJAX so I assume I am making a silly mistake.

I know my function is definitely getting the intended variable data passed to it, after doing a quick  `window.alert(myVar);` within the function.

This is what I have so far:

```
    function getTeamMembers(teamID,lecturer_id) {

        var functionName = 'loadTeamMembersChart';

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'dashboard.php',
        dataType: 'json',
         data: { functionName: 'loadTeamMembersChart', teamID: teamID, lecturer_id: lecturer_id },
         success: function(){
            alert("OK");
        },
        fail: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        },
        always: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
         }
       ); 
   }
```

Before calling the desired php function, I collect the sent varaibles just before my php Dashboard class starts at the top of the file. I plan to pass the variables across once I can be sure that they are actually there.

However, when I click the button, nothing can be echo'd from the sent data.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){


if (!empty($_POST["teamID"]) && !empty($_POST["lecturer_id"]))
{
  $teamID = $_POST['teamID'];
  $lecturer_id = $_POST['lecturer_id'];
  echo $teamID;
  echo " is your teamID";
} 
else 
{

  echo "no teamID supplied";
}

}
```

Comment: What's the code that handles "functionname" and "arguments" from your ajax call?

Comment: Where is the method or function you're posting to?

Comment: @Devon at the top of my page just before my Desktop class php is defined I have                                                                                      
                                                                                             
`$functionname = $_POST['loadTeamMembersChart'];`
`$arguments = $_POST[[teamID, lecturer_id]];`

Comment: Well.. that wouldn't work.   None of those post keys are used in your ajax request.  Your post keys are functionname and arguments.

Comment: @Devon ah yes, I have updated my question but still no luck...

Answer (score -1):

you `else` statement in you success function , and that's not how you set fail callback, try the following and tell us what do you see in the console.

```
function getTeamMembers(teamID,lecturer_id) {

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'dashboard.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {functionname: 'loadTeamMembersChart', arguments: [teamID, lecturer_id]},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        fail: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        },
        always: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks - your answer needed a little editing though...here: `fail: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        },
        always: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
         }
    ); 
   }`

Answer (score -2):

Seems like your function is not returning a success message when getting into the following statement.

```
if ($result) {

        "Awesome, it worked"
     }
```

Please try to add a return before the string.

```
if ($result) {
        return "Awesome, it worked";
     }
```

It can be other factors, but the information you provided is not enough to make any further analysis.

Comment: `return` here isn't going to help the OP